# Limit contenteditable div to visible part

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, textarea

I have a div, which has `contenteditable=true`. Now, if I enter a longer text, it goes over the bottom. I don't want that. I want the text to stop and block any other text.

This is the solution like I want to have it: http://jsfiddle.net/37Jnn/

The problem here is that this is a `textarea` and it isn't working with my editable `div`.

Here is my editable div: http://jsfiddle.net/N4tTp/1/

Any thoughts?

Comment: add `overflow:hidden` to `div`

Comment: Want it to be scrollable? overflow:auto will do the trick as well.

Answer (score 0):

Credit goes to Mohsen but I think this post should have a formal answer:
You're looking for the css style of:

```
overflow:hidden;
```

on the div in question. To make the div scrollable, set overflow to:

```
overflow:auto;
```

Comment: i dont want to have it scrollable, i just want to end my text there, but thanks :)

Comment: @Phlume what is the reason of commenting an answer instead of posting it as an answer? Either he doesn't want credit or he is unsure of his suggestion (in which case dudewad should get credit, because he is sure enough to post it) or he simply doesn't have the desire to type out a full answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could save the state of the div (original and after each successful input) and after input events check the div size and restore the state if the size is too big.

The advantage of this solution over the `overflow:hidden;` one is that the div actually doesn't have the extra content. If someone was to select all the text in it after inputting too much, the extra characters wouldn't be part of the selection.

Answer (score 0):

While it isn't the most elegant way to do it, it does work.

HTML:

```
<div class="myDiv" contenteditable=true>This text is in the box.... but this is not in the box</div>
```

CSS:

```
.myDiv {
    background: #acacac;
    width:60px;
    height: 60px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Javascript:

```
var text = undefined;
$(function(){
    while($('.myDiv').get(0).scrollHeight > $('.myDiv').height()) {
        $('.myDiv').text($('.myDiv').text().slice(0,-1));
    }
});
$('.myDiv').bind('keydown', function(e) {
    text = $('.myDiv').text();
    if($('.myDiv').get(0).scrollHeight > $('.myDiv').height() && e.which != 8) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
$('.myDiv').bind('keyup', function() {
    if($('.myDiv').get(0).scrollHeight > $('.myDiv').height()) {
        $('.myDiv').text(text);
    }
 });
```